# background noises on Google voice recognition android

Tags: android, voice-recognition, google-voice

I managed to create a very nice android app that allways listen to the client and perform tasks using voice commands (google voice recognition).
the problem is that in the car its working exteremly bad.
i have tried youtube voice search also and there is the same issue.
i wanted to know if there is any way to filter background noises on google voice?

Comment: You can use CMUSphinx http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid, it's lastest code has great noise cancellation features. The ability to restrict the vocabulary can also improve accuracy in noisy condition.

Comment: I allready thought about it, the problem is that hebrew not supported :/.

Comment: There are commercial acoustic models for pocketsphinx for Hebrew.

Comment: There is a commercial model for Hebrew actually, you can contact me if you are interested.